# Jquery Variable Accessing in html

Tags: jquery

how to store the returned function value in 'x' ??? i need this because, i wanna use a hover function on images and respectives image's src will varies.

```
<script>
var x;
$(document).ready(function(){$(":image").attr("src");
alert(x);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
Name: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
Compatible: <input type="image" src="compatible_ie.gif" width="31" height="30">
</form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? `x` is not even set! :(

Comment: This function returns nothing. Anyway where do you want to append that variable.

Comment: `var x = $(":image").attr("src");` if I get right what you want to achieve.

Comment: look at this http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-s-duos-s7562/p/itmdddbup6fn8mmy?pid=MOBDDDBRHVWQZHYY&ref=3378deb3-969d-4a46-a93b-90be4935ee64 this is what i want to inherit in to my site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this i hope u will understand how to do it.
Html:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://web.utk.edu/~ihouse/wp-content/uploads/icon-smiley.jpg" alt="Image" class="big" />
</div>

<img src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/fullsize/scrap/smiley-grin.png" alt="Image" class="small" />
<img src="http://www.skinbase.org/files/archive/shots/638/Az-Smiley-Face-Icon.jpg"  class="small"/>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oldSrc = null;
    $(".small").hover( function(){
        // get the src of hovered image
        var src= $(this).attr('src');
        //get the big image src and store it in the global variable.
        oldSrc = $(".big").attr('src');
        //set the hovered image src into the big one.
        $(".big").attr('src',src )
    }, function() {
        // reset the big image
        $(".big").attr( "src" , oldSrc);
    });
 });
```

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw2pc/2/)**

Comment: Thank you Bios, but i have one more small doubt,,, up to know everything is fine. how to fix the image(in big class) which is selected from small class?

Comment: Comment `$(".big").attr( "src" , oldSrc);` in the callback function you will get that. Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw2pc/3/)**

Comment: Change/Edit your question so that it will be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

OKay, in case, if you wanna change the image on hover, I assume that, then you need to use something like this:

```
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="Image" class="hover" />
<img src="img2.jpg" alt="Image" class="hover" />
<img src="img3.jpg" alt="Image" class="hover" />
```

Have a hover image for these, say `img1a.jpg`, `img2a.jpg`, `img3a.jpg` and you can call them this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hover").hover(function(){
        var a = $this.attr("src")
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
        $(this).data("src", a);
    }, function(){
        var a = $this.data("src")
        $(this).data("src", $(this).attr("src"));
        $(this).attr("src", a);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the value of src attribute.
Just store it in a variable and use wherever you want.

```
<script>
var x;
$(document).ready(function(){var x=$("input:image").attr("src");
    alert(x);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  Name: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
 Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
Compatible: <input type="image" src="compatible_ie.gif" width="31" height="30">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: If you feel this answer is appropriate then dont forget to accept as answer